# Calling external function in show()

Tags: jquery, function

I have this function inside file index.js:

```
$('#menu_aEmpresa').on('click', function(){
    $('#aEmpresa_mainContent').show();
    $('#aNossaArte_mainContent').hide();
    $('#contactos_mainContent').hide();
  });
```

... and this one on file aEmpresa_intro.js:

```
function aEmpresa_Opening_run(){
    $.when(aEmpresa_horizontalBrackets_01(), aEmpresa_horizontalBrackets_02(), aEmpresa_horizontalBrackets_03(), aEmpresa_horizontalBrackets_04()).done(function(){
      $.when(aEmpresa_horizontalBrackets_05(), aEmpresa_horizontalBrackets_06(), aEmpresa_horizontalBrackets_07(), aEmpresa_horizontalBrackets_08()).done(function(){
        $.when(aEmpresa_textBox()).done(function(){
          $.when(aEmpresa_textBoxBtns_01(), aEmpresa_textBoxBtns_02()).done(function(){
            $.when(aEmpresa_photoBox(), aEmpresa_facebook()).done(function(){
              aEmpresa_photoBoxBtns_01(); aEmpresa_photoBoxBtns_02();
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

The HTML script links:

```
<!-- A Empresa scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/aEmpresa_intro.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/aEmpresa_exit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/aEmpresa.js"></script>
<!-- Index scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index_intro.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index_infobox_pt.js"></script>
```

Basically, the function **aEmpresa_Opening_run()** is an intro opening for when the **#aEmpresa_mainContent** is shown.

How do call the intro function when the show() happens?

Thanx

Pedro

Answer (score 0):

Use complete event, here is documentation: [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

```
$('#menu_aEmpresa').on('click', function(){
    $('#aEmpresa_mainContent').show(function(){
       aEmpresa_Opening_run();
    });
    $('#aNossaArte_mainContent').hide('rocksMenu_pt.html');
    $('#contactos_mainContent').hide('contactos_pt.html');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'm getting a ReferenceError: aEmpresa_Opening_run is not defined - aEmpresa_Opening_run(); because the aEmpresa_Opening_run() is located in another file. How do I fix this?

Comment: @Pedro You must include JS file with aEmpresa_Opening_run() function, before you are using $('#menu_aEmpresa').on(.. action.

Comment: All my js files are linked inside the html file. Did you mean link to it inside the index.js file?